# Error when importing the ssl module in Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, anaconda

When I run `import ssl` in Python 3.7.4, with the Anaconda Prompt, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Google brought up an error that occurred in PyCharm and a Github page, which none of the answers were able to solve my issue. I've tried reinstall Anaconda3 many times, each time making sure that it was completely removed. I don't know if its something to do with my machine (Win 10). I have tried to manually install the SSL module for python without any luck.

Comment: This is a rather common issue AFAIK, did you search the interwebs before asking ?

Comment: @LoneWanderer, yes, I have been experiencing and trying to solve this issue for over 24hr now.